# Reverse numbers in stacked barplot in R

Tags: r, ggplot2, bar-chart

I created a stacked [barplot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q2jE1.png) that counts tickets by different state, unfortunately the related numbers are reverse of that how they should be and how they also are in the [data frame](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fYC9v.png)

Here is my code for the plot:

```
library(ggplot2)
PlotTotal <- ggplot(data=DevBarPlot, aes(x=DayOfMonth, y=NumOfTickets, fill=State), break(31)) +
    geom_bar(stat="identity")+
    scale_fill_manual(values=c("lightsteelblue2", "lightsteelblue3"))+
    coord_cartesian(ylim=c(2000,30000))+
    geom_text(aes(y=NumOfTickets, label=NumOfTickets), vjust=-1, color="black", size=3.4)+
    labs(title="Num of Tickets per Day", x="Day of Month", y = "Number of Tickets")+
    theme_classic() + 
    theme(legend.position="top")+
    theme(legend.background = element_rect(fill="white",size=0.3, linetype="solid",colour ="lightsteelblue3"))+    
    theme(plot.title = element_text(color="lightsteelblue2", size=14, face="bold",hjust=0.5))
```

Comment: maybe th reverse `rev` function will come in handy

Comment: thanks, where would you insert the rev?

Comment: Sorry. Your code isn't reproducible and I'm not a ggplot guy. Although hacky, it does seem to reason that you could reverse appropriate columns in your data to achieve your desired output, e.g., `df[,1] <- rev(df[,1])`

Comment: Hi @MowOsterberger. If my answer below solves your problem, I'd be grateful if you could upvote it and mark it as accepted. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

It's helpful to provide some sample data (see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example/5963610#5963610) for help). In this case I've created a sample data frame from the data in your two images, guessing that the other state is `NY`.

```r
data <- data.frame(
  State = c(rep('NOTNY', 5), rep('NY', 5)),
  NumOfTickets = c(5893, 5681, 4629, 2508, 5363,
                   23322, 20827, 15259, 6271, 18192),
  DayOfMonth = rep(1:5, 2)
)

data
#>    State NumOfTickets DayOfMonth
#> 1  NOTNY         5893          1
#> 2  NOTNY         5681          2
#> 3  NOTNY         4629          3
#> 4  NOTNY         2508          4
#> 5  NOTNY         5363          5
#> 6     NY        23322          1
#> 7     NY        20827          2
#> 8     NY        15259          3
#> 9     NY         6271          4
#> 10    NY        18192          5
```

In terms of the plot, you needed to include `position = "stack"` in your geom_text. I've also tweaked a few other bits and bobs e.g. `vjust = 1.5` and using `geom_col()`.

```r
library(ggplot2)

ggplot(data, aes(x = DayOfMonth, y = NumOfTickets, fill = State)) +
  geom_col() +
  scale_fill_manual(values = c("lightsteelblue2", "lightsteelblue3")) +
  geom_text(aes(y = NumOfTickets, label = NumOfTickets),
            position = "stack", vjust = 1.5, size = 3.4) +
  labs(title = "Num of Tickets per Day",
       x = "Day of Month", y = "Number of Tickets") +
  theme_classic() +
  theme(legend.position = "top") +
  theme(legend.background = element_rect(
    fill = "white", size = 0.3, linetype = "solid", colour = "lightsteelblue3")) +
  theme(plot.title = element_text(
    color = "lightsteelblue2", size = 14, face = "bold", hjust = 0.5))
```

[image]